# QueryParam binding with enum in jersey

Tags: rest, jersey

I have a rest URL like this http://www.localhost.com/service/resource?status=ACTIVE,PASSIVE and I have a method like this

```
@GET
public Resource resource(@QueryParam("status") Collection<STATUS> statusList){
}
```

where STATUS is an enum?

```
public enum STATUS{
    ACTIVE,PASSIVE,DISABLED
}
```

My question is there a way for the query param status to be automatically converted to a list of enum type STATUS in jersey or do I have to write my own provider for this?

Answer (score 56):

From the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/QueryParam.html), the `@QueryParam` annotated type must either:

1. Be a primitive type
2. Have a constructor that accepts a single `String` argument
3. Have a static method named `valueOf` or `fromString` that accepts a single `String` argument (see, for example, `Integer.valueOf(String)`)
4. Be `List<T>`, `Set<T>` or `SortedSet<T>`, where `T` satisfies 2 or 3 above. The resulting collection is read-only.

For your case I would go with the second option by wrapping the enum in a simple class:

```
public class StatusList {
  private List<STATUS> statusList;

  public StatusList(String toParse) {
    //code to split the parameter into a list of statuses 
  }

  public List<STATUS> getStatusList() {
    return this.statusList;
  }
}
```

Then change your method to:

```
@GET
public Resource resource(@QueryParam("status") StatusList statusList){
}
```

Comment: But every enum in Java has a valueOf(String) method. Therefore 3 is fulfilled, so he could just go from Collection<STATUS> to a List<STATUS> and no wrapping will be needed. Isn't that right?

Comment: I think that's the best approach either.

Comment: What with optional values? valueOf(Null) throws an exception

Comment: It seems that if your enum has a fromValue(String) method, it takes precedence over the default valueOf(String) method. Nice to know if you need some custom behaviour (as I did).

Answer (score 9):

Try with this:

```
http://www.localhost.com/service/resource?status=ACTIVE&status=PASSIVE
```

```
@QueryParam("status") List<STATUS> statusList
```

Comment: The end game was sending everything in capital, as enums were in capital

Answer (score 9):

Add this method to your enum:

```
public static YourEnum fromString(final String s) {
    return YourEnum.valueOf(s);
}
```

Comment: Isn't he going to use valueOf() anyway? Every enum supports this

Comment: @PieterDeBie I read about it a long time ago, so I can't provide any links, but I definitely remember that jersey specifically recognises `fromString` method with that ^ signature. It is essentially same as `valueOf` however I am not sure why jersey doesn't play well with `valueOf`.

Comment: @BabkenVardanyan - the problem isn't that jax-rs doesn't work well with valueOf - it works fine as far as it goes. It just doesn't go far enough. valueOf requires uppercase exact matches of the string. When you write your own fromString, you can convert mixed case to uppercase before you call valueOf.

Comment: I'm using JAX-RS with Jersey 1.18 and it's not using `fromString`. I wonder which version supports this.

Comment: In the end I solved upgrading to a newer Jackson and annotation the method `@JsonCreator`.